# how to add a checkbox with condition in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have created one tabular form(legacy page) in oracle apex and in some columns i have given type checkbox.I just want to add a condition that if that column value is 'y' then it is already checked otherwise unchecked.
please help me regarding this.

Comment: please give any solutions if you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding case statement in the select query and give the conditions there.

Answer (score 0):

Set SQL query something like this:

```
select ID, name, my_column
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2( 
p_idx => 2, p_value => ID, 
p_checked_values => case when my_column = 'Y' then ID else null end
) checkbox
from my_table;
```